# cvt.s.w Instruction in MIPS does not seem to do anything

Tags: casting, floating-point, mips, precision

My professor asks "What does the cvt.s.w instruction do? What problem would occur if we didn't use it?"

In my assembler, even if I remove those lines of code, the program still runs fine. Am I missing something here or does cvt.s.w do literally nothing in this case? Here's the code he provides with the question:

```
.data
    THIRD:  .float 3.3
.text
   li $t0, 10       # Put 10 in coprocessor
   mtc1 $t0, $f0
   cvt.s.w $f0, $f0

   li $t0, 11       # Put 1.1 in coprocessor
   mtc1 $t0, $f1
   cvt.s.w $f1, $f1
   div.s $f1, $f1, $f0

   li $t0, 22       # Put 2.2 in coprocessor
   mtc1 $t0, $f2
   cvt.s.w $f2, $f2
   div.s $f2, $f2, $f0

   la $t0, THIRD        # Put 3.3 in coprocessor
   l.s $f3, 0($t0)
    
   add.s $f12, $f1, $f2 # Add and print results
   add.s $f12, $f12, $f3
   li $v0, 2
   syscall

   li $a0, 10       # Print newline
   li $v0, 11
   syscall

   add.s $f12, $f2, $f3 # Add and print results
   add.s $f12, $f12, $f1
   li $v0, 2
   syscall

   li $v0, 10       # Exit program
   syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instructor is messing with you.  The examples have been carefully constructed so as to result in no visible changes.

Did you look at the values in the debugger?

Maybe try to print the various intermediate values?

The values of the intermediates are most certainly different if you don't use the cvt.s.w.  Without the conversion, these numbers are taken as very, very small floating point values.

Amazingly, division still sort of works, though, since the relative relationship between the numbers remains.

Also, when we compute a large value + a small value in floating point, often the small value disappears.  Think of it this way: in 3 digits let's add 3.14 to 0.000456.  Both numbers have 3 digits of precision, but what do we get when adding them?  3.14, in three digits.

Single float only has about 6.5 digits of precision so very small numbers added to normal sized numbers, the only thing that remains it the normal sized number.

Here's a version of the exact same but adds printing of intermediate values.  You'll notice some of them are quite different.

With the cvt.s.w ***included*** the output is:

```
11.0
1.1
22.0
2.2
3.3000002
6.6000004
5.5
6.6
-- program is finished running --
```

and with the cvt.s.w ***excluded*** the output is:

```
1.4E-44
1.5E-44
1.1
3.1E-44
2.2
3.3000002
6.6000004
5.5
6.6
-- program is finished running --
```

```
    .data
        THIRD:  .float 3.3
    .text
       li $t0, 10       # Put 10 in coprocessor
       mtc1 $t0, $f0
       cvt.s.w $f0, $f0

       mov.s $f12, $f0
       li $v0, 2
       syscall

       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       li $t0, 11       # Put 1.1 in coprocessor
       mtc1 $t0, $f1
       cvt.s.w $f1, $f1
   
       mov.s $f12, $f1
       li $v0, 2
       syscall
   
       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       div.s $f1, $f1, $f0
   
       mov.s $f12, $f1
       li $v0, 2
       syscall

       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

           li $t0, 22       # Put 2.2 in coprocessor
       mtc1 $t0, $f2
       cvt.s.w $f2, $f2
   
       mov.s $f12, $f2
       li $v0, 2
       syscall
   
       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       div.s $f2, $f2, $f0
   
       mov.s $f12, $f2
       li $v0, 2
       syscall

       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       la $t0, THIRD        # Put 3.3 in coprocessor
       l.s $f3, 0($t0)
    
       add.s $f12, $f1, $f2 # Add and print results
       li $v0, 2
       syscall
   
       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       add.s $f12, $f12, $f3
       li $v0, 2
       syscall

       li $a0, 10       # Print newline
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       add.s $f12, $f2, $f3 # Add and print results
       li $v0, 2
       syscall
   
       li $a0, 10
       li $v0, 11
       syscall

       add.s $f12, $f12, $f1
       li $v0, 2
       syscall

       li $v0, 10       # Exit program
       syscall
```